# Domain Model or Domain Object ? - Definitions

Tags: php, oop, zend-framework, domain-model, domain-object

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

We may say Domain Model to represent:

**a)** The M part of a MVC structure, having on the M part, a Domain Driven Design pattern applied.

**b)** A scheme of entities, their attributes and relationships in a certain way. Could also represent a M part on a MVC but, on this case, regardless the pattern used.

**c)** A Domain Model Design Pattern where "a Domain Model creates a web of interconnected objects";

**d)** As a Domain Object (that could be, for example, an object on our MVC model regargind a certain domain);

Could we say that **d)** is the same as **b)** ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shorty answer: no, they are not the same.

Domain objects actually are *(removed)* .. look at the comment from @meze .. there is a link.

This part *"scheme of entities, their attributes and relationships"* is kinda related to structure of the data. But you Domain objects should not be aware of fact that they are stored or even that there exists a storage. That is responsibility of Data access layer.

And the Domain model is the overarching structure which manipulates different types and numbers of Domain objects.

Comment: Why are domain objects value objects? [Domain Object](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject) "should know how to maintain business logic", "identify themselves".

Comment: @meze Yeah .. your right , i shouldn't compare them to value objects. I guess i thought of a way too simple usecase, that's why the "value object" seemed to be a good description. My bad.

Comment: So I have one answer that says yes... another answer that says no. Can you agree ? So that we can have a clear answer for this. :)

Comment: Ok. :) I got your answer. And thanks teresko. Because, already on my earlier question you have spotted that my doubt was here, even before I did. ;)

Comment: Here is the example i like to use for distinction: domain model is **library** , domain objects are **books** and **patrons** , data access layer is **librarian**

Comment: So we could say that books and patrons are part of the library but they are not necessarly the library. In order to be the library, we will need: books, patrons **and** librarian. So, we will never have the case where a Domain Object IS (ipsis verbis) a Domain Model. - ?

Comment: Not if you do it in a sustainable way. The point in this separation is to decouple your business logic from your database logic. You **can** write a domain model that is actually a domain object + data access layer. That is the ActiveRecord pattern , but is it tightly coupled to the database and the code is really hard to test.

Answer (score 3):

Domain Object is an element of Domain Model. Domain object is **b)**.

Comment: Despite what @teresko noted, we could also say (providing other definitions) that a Domain Model IS a Domain Object on those cases where, the Domain Object is AN ELEMENT of a Domain Model ? But perhaps here we are not on a real "is" relation... but more on a "has". Interesting. This recalls me the "has-a" / "is-a" relations.

Comment: @MEM, classes and objects are elements of object-oriented programming. But we can't say classes and objects are object-oriented programming ;p